# Why does my keyboard stop working after a screen lock?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, i3, screen-lock

I am using i3, [betterlockscreen](https://github.com/betterlockscreen/betterlockscreen) and Arch Linux. It is configured to lock itself after some minutes of inactivity.

When this happens and I unlock, the keyboard does not appear to work thereafter. My normal i3 key mappings for switching windows, opening programs, moving focus do not work. If I click on a text box and try to type no letters appear.

This can be resolved by doing certain things:

- If multiple i3 windows are open, clicking on a different one to switch focus makes keyboard work again
- Clicking on systray icons and opening a window also fixes it
- If multiple workspaces are active, clicking on the numbers to switch them fixes the keyboard

Clicking on an already active workspace or window does not restore keyboard function.

Strangely, if I lock the screen manually by running the lock command in a terminal, the keyboard does not stop working. I also thought that an unrelated process is disabling the keyboard, but then how come I am able to type in the password to unlock? The keyboard is wired and has no "sleep" function that I'm aware of, even if it did it certainly doesn't make sense for it to be woken by mouse activity.

What causes this?

Note: This may be a long-running question because to reproduce it I must wait for the computer to lock itself. I will edit the question accordingly.